# String Length with Scalars and Vectors in APL

Tags: apl

I just started learning APL a couple of weeks ago, so this may sound like a newbie question.

Let `B` be a string, which in APL terms can be either a scalor or a vector. If it's a scalar, `⍴B` returns null rather than the length of the string as I want.

```
B←'QR'
⍴B ⍝ returns 2

B←'Q'
⍴B ⍝ returns null
```

I discovered one way around that:

```
⍴1↓'X',B ⍝ concatenating X and then removing it returns a value of 1
```

That works, but it seems a little hokey, so I'm wondering if there is a more standard way to find string length.

Is it just me or does this seem a little inconsistent? The tutorial I read said to think of a scalar as a point similar to the way it is in vector algebra. But how is it that concatenating a scalar to a scalar makes a vector, but dropping a scalar from a vector never results in a scalar?

I'm really enjoying APL, so this question isn't meant as criticism. My question is, what's the best way to find string length? And, if anyone can shed a little light on this seeming inconsistency, it would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correct. ⍴,B shows you the count of characters.

Comment: @CrazyMetal - Thats true if there are more than 1, but if you assign `B←'A'`, it is considered a scalar and `⍴B` returns null. If you use my little trick above, it returns 1.

Comment: I wrote `⍴,B`. In my opinion that is the standard way to find string length.

Comment: Cool! That works great. I guess I overlooked the comma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reasons that concatenating X and removing it works, is that the catenation produces a vector. Removing X with `1↓` then leaves it as a vector, as an empty vector to be precise. And the length of vectors can be measured with ⍴. That is also what CrazyMetal's solution does: monadic `,` transforms its argument (scalar or array of any dimension) into a vector. And measuring its rho gives you the answer you were looking for: **the** standard way to find string length.

```
⍴,B
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't address the inconsistency part. You can get a vector from concatenating scalars, but you can't get a scalar by dropping elements. I realize that it remains a vector, but it doesn't make sense to me why. However, I like solution. It's much neater than my solution. Thanks!

Comment: Dropping an element means you changing the size ob the object, and that is all. You do not change the rank by changing the size.
I see that is must be difficult to grasp initially, but once you get used to "array thinking", it will feel natural ;-)

Comment: A related observation:  monadic take (sorry no APL chars on ipad keyboard!) returns the first element of a vector as a scalar.  I'm afraid I'm a bit far removed from APL these days to recall the reason for apparent inconsistency cited.

Comment: Are you using Dyalog? The behaviour of monadic take there depends on quadML, the migration level. And there is a setting (sorry, travelling right now w/o manual and APL) where it would behave like the "first"-function...

Comment: Sorry MBaas just saw yr question.  My main APL experience was IBM mainframe APL2.

Comment: The "inconsistency" is an aspect of the notation.  A lone single character or numeric quantity is interpreted to be scalar.
rho 'A' is iota 0, i.e. a scalar.
rho 'AB' is 2, a 2 element vector.
rho ,'A' is 1, a one element vector
The same is true for numbers, rho 42 is a scalar.
Also, you can test for rank with rho rho, i.e. rho rho 'A' would be zero, a scalar.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour that you see is caused by an inconsistency in the APL syntax. A sequence of characters enclosed in single-quotes creates an array of those characters. For example, `'foo'` creates an array of the characters `f`, `o` and `o`. Calling `⍴` on this array shows the expected result:

```
      ⍴'foo'
3
```

However, these is an exception to this rule, and this is where the syntax is inconsistent. When you specify a single character inside the single quotes, you do not create an array of a single character, but rather the character itself is returned. This is why `⍴'f'` returns an empty array, since the value is a scalar.

As was suggested by Pé de Leão, you can use the `,` function to ensure that a scalar value becomes an array which is why using `⍴,` works regardless of whether its argument is a scalar or an array.

Because of this inconsistency, GNU APL has an extension that allows you to use `"` instead of `'` when typing strings. The only difference between them is that `"` always creates an array, even for single characters.